# Firebase Database is taking too much time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Database to store information about dog owners and their dogs. My structure of database is

```
dogs:
   dog_id
        nameDog
        dogOwnerId
        dogBreed
```

It is taking to much time to execute. By this line I added the value listeners to get dogs of the currect user.

```
databaseReference.child(FIREBASE_CHILD_DOGS).orderByChild("dogOwnerId").equalTo(dogOwnerId).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Before that my structure was

```
dogs:
  dogOwnerId:
    dog_id
        nameDog
        dogBreed
```

Both of my structure take around 35 s to synchronize data from the database.
Do you know what it could be wrong? Poor internet connection?

Comment: Have you looked at indexing your data (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)?

Comment: How much data do you have under `dogs`? What's the bandwidth of your connection? And do you have an index on `dogOwnerId`? Between these three questions, the time it takes to execute the query should be fairly simple math. If you find it hard to explain: set up a jsbin that reproduces the performance problem and I'll take a look.

Comment: I store 9 properties about a dog including photo as Base64 but I tested with empty photo. It took much time anyway. Btw I tried to store images in Firebase Storage, it took around 2 mins to get the image using Glide. So I decided to store them as Base64 which isnt probably the best solution. The bandwitdh of my connection is 10.6 Mbps. I tried the index on dogOwnerId. Sometimes its better, around 10s. Probably it should be faster, shouldnt be?

Comment: Store the image in Firebase Storage rather than base64 encode it. Use the download url to link the two. That will drastically speed up your download time. Also, consider what @FrankvanPuffelen said. Look at all the data under `dogs` and see if you could create an index instead.

Comment: I created index on dogOwnerId. I tried to add to downloadUrl to the dogPhoto. It was slow to download the photo. Even it had only less than 1 MB. Where could be problem with Storage?

Comment: There are too many unknowns in here. As said before: if you find it hard to explain the performance, set up a jsbin (the performance shouldn't be significantly different between Android and web) that reproduces the performance problem and I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok I will try it. I am not really familiar with javascript :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/behofijuji/edit?js,console I realized I set the index wrongly because the information about dog are nested under the dog id.

Answer (score 0):

To cache data locally, you should make a class, which extends Application and place it in the manifest like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    /* Enable disk persistence  */
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Then add the following in manifest inside the application tag:

```
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

This method reduces a lot of time and works even if the user is offline.